# How can I insert into to a SQL Server database data from an online CSV?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to perform a dataload every day from a csv available online e.g. http://www.supplier.com/products.csv
Once I've dumped the csv into a sql table I can do the processing I then need to update / insert etc. The problem is that I don't know how to automate the dataload.

I was hoping I could use a SQL job / task, scheduled to run each day at 06:00, give it a uri and that it could then access the data in the csv...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can schedule a SQL Agent job to download the file locally and use [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx):

```
CREATE TABLE StagingCSV
(
   col1 VARCHAR(60),
   col2 VARCHAR(60),
   col3 VARCHAR(60),
   col4 VARCHAR(60),
    -- ...
)
GO
```

(error rows will be ignored)

```
BULK
INSERT StagingCSV
FROM 'c:\mycsvfile.txt'
WITH
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Other methods:

[About Bulk Import and Bulk Export Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187042.aspx)

[Importing Bulk Data by Using BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx)

You can use Powershell to download a file:

```
$clnt = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "http://www.supplier.com/products.csv "
$file = "c:\temp\Mycsv.txt"
$clnt.DownloadFile($url, $file)
```

Comment: This will be on a virtual dedicated server, not sure about the version of SQL it will have, but the Powershell approach is interesting - I've used WSH in the past and this looks similar. I will try it out and let you know how I get on

Comment: Awesome - the Powershell script does just what I need. It's lovely and lightweight, I'll have no problem sticking that on the hosted server and scheduling it. I might even take it a stage further and use that to invoke the actual data loading process!

Answer (score 2):

Another simple (although not free, but still rather cheap) solution is to use the **SQL#** library which would allow you to do this in just a few lines of T-SQL.  This would make it really easy to automate via a SQL Agent Job.

You could emulate the Powershell method (suggested by Mitch) with a single command to grab the CSV file and then read it into the table with another command:

```
DECLARE @Dummy VARBINARY(1)
SELECT @Dummy = SQL#.INET_DownloadFile('http://www.location.tld/file.csv',  
       'C:\file.csv')

INSERT INTO dbo.RealTable (Column1, Column2, ...)
    EXEC SQL#.File_SplitIntoFields 'C:\file.csv', ',', 0, NULL, NULL
```

OR, you could bypass going to the file system by reading the CSV file straight into a local variable, splitting that on the carriage-returns into a Temp Table, and then split that into your table:

```
CREATE TABLE #CSVRows (CSV VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @Contents VARBINARY(MAX)
SELECT @Contents = SQL#.INET_DownloadFile('http://www.location.tld/file.csv',  
       NULL)

INSERT INTO #CSVRows (CSV)
    SELECT SplitVal
    FROM SQL#.String_Split(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Contents),  
         CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), 1)

INSERT INTO dbo.RealTable (Column1, Column2, ...)
    EXEC SQL#.String_SplitIntoFields 'SELECT CSV FROM #CSVRows', ',', NULL
```

You can find SQL# at: http://www.SQLsharp.com/

I am the author of the SQL# library, but this seems like a valid solution to the question.

Comment: the SQL# library looks pretty interesting - being able to run everything from SQL would certainly be an advantage to me, so I wasn't reliant on the file being downloaded. Are there any special permissions required to set this up? This will be on a hosted server, so I might not have SA account, I'm concerned that I wouldn't be able to 'install' it.

Comment: @Simon: For any SQLCLR project you need to enable CLR at the server level. I would think this would be already done by the hosting company and if not it could be requested. For CLR functionality that looks outside of the DB (such as internet and file system functions) the DB needs to be set to TRUSTWORTHY mode (well, there is another way but I am working on it now and don't support it yet). That requires dbo access which you should have. If you have any other questions or want to test this out, you can go to the SQLsharp.com website and contact me directly from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen an example where you can bulk insert directly from a url.

So, for the remainder, use a sql job and bulk insert.

Bulk inserts made easy: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1207

Here's a quick excerpt:

> BULK INSERT dbo.ImportTest  FROM
>   'C:\ImportData.txt'  WITH (
>   FIELDTERMINATOR =',', FIRSTROW = 2 )

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform the file download by using an Integration Services Task:
http://www.sqlis.com/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx

Comment: I assume SSIS requires a full version of SQL? I couldn't find it in my local SQL Express - or mention of it on Fasthosts (who I will be hosting this solution on)