# Import Data from CSV to SQL Server Task

Tags: import, sql-server-2012, task

I have a flat file that will be downloaded to a server every night at 1 AM. I right clicked the data base, then tasks, then import data, then saved the import SSIS package.

When I try to run the package it works the first time then says the table already exists, error executing query, failed with the following error: there is already an object named csvtest in the database.

I guess I need to drop an recreate the table everytime the import runs but I don't know how to do that within the "Execute Package Utility"

I'm getting a bit over my head and lost, any ideas how I can accomplish importing a csv with SQL Server Management Studio automatically with a task?

Comment: If you don't need to do any transformation, then BULK INSERT is a simpler and better option than SSIS.

Comment: how can I run bulk insert automatically? I can write it in SQL but then what?

Comment: you can schedule it in SQL Server Agent

Comment: thanks... have any good examples or links?

Comment: a good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281617/how-can-i-insert-into-to-a-sql-server-database-data-from-an-online-csv